# Ignore same file in different folders with .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

How do I use .gitignore to ignore a file that can be in more than one folder, having the same name?

I have

`-folderA
      -folderAA
           -file.json
 -folderB
      -folderBB
          -file.json`

What I need is an expression to ignore both *file.json* in **folderA/folderAA** and **folderB/folderBB** without having to use two expressions for each file.

*EDIT START*
The file is already tracked by git
*EDIT END*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `**` wildcard to specify any directory

for example:
`**/file.json`

Comment: Ok, this works for files not yet commited and pushed, but file.json already existed and was previously commited and pushed. Now I just want to keep the changes to myself without pushing to the repo, but it keeps showing up in the unstaged files marked as a modification. Anything I need to do?

Comment: Then you need to do `git rm folderA/folderAA/file.json` for each file. And commit it and push it.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding `file.json` into .gitignore without any prefix works well.

Answer (score -1):

Based from Git documentation here (http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) :

```
/**/file.json
```

if the JSON files have different names, consider using `/**/*.json` but careful, this will excludes ALL JSON files